# Broadcasting event from parent to child fires all parent's children in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent component and a child component.
In my parent component I have an event on a `span`:

```
<span @click="toggle(model.id)" class="open-folder">[{{open ? '-' : '+'}}]</span>
```

which fires the `toggle` function

```
methods: {
        toggle: function(id_epic) {
            this.open = !this.open;

            this.$broadcast('loadTasks', id_epic);
        }
    },
```

in this function I call the `loadTasks` method from the child component with `id_epic` parameter.

The parent can have `n` children linked to it, but I only want to fire the first child method not all.
When I click on the span it fires the event for all `n` children of the parent's tree.

EDIT: The parent and it's children are generated recursively, so the child can also be a parent on it's own.(Like a folder structure)

How can I fix this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`$broadcast` is used to send event to child components. In your parent component you're triggering the event `loadTasks` from the `toggle` method. This is good.

You're sending a `parameter` along in the event, in your case `id_epic`

Now in your child component, you will need something like this. You need to get the `id` you're sending in your child component.

```
events : {
    'loadTask' : function(param) {
               //check for the id_epic here
     }
 }
```

> EDIT: The parent and it's children are generated recursively, so the child can also be a parent on it's own.(Like a folder structure)

You should also re-think that part, if you have too many nested components, things can get easily out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to stop the propagation of an event by using a second parameter in the child listener. The second parameter is passed the event object to which you can can call `stopProgation()` and prevent additional children from also receiving the broadcasted event.

Consider adding the following code to your child listener.

```
events:{
    'loadTask': function(param,event){
        event.stopPropagtion();
        // Handle the param as needed.
    }
}
```

Of course this system of event handling is only for Vue.js 1.0 as in Vue.js 2.0+ event broadcasting and dispatching has been depreciated in favor of a data store such as Vuex. So you may want to consider using a method which will upgrade compatible.

Comment: Event broadcasting and dispatching were not deprecated in favor of data stores but a message pump architecture, each component has an `$on`, `$off`, `$once`, and `$emit` function to handle local events. Creating an empty global Vue instance is the recommended method for decoupled event handling.

giving a +1 for the correct Vuejs 1.0 solution though

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `this.$children[0].$emit()` to send the event to the first child instance. though it would probably be better to use a more explicit scheme and have children register handlers with the parent or vice versa.